# Python: Printing a single element as a string and printing a list when there are multiple elements in list

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary (where the counts (values) are sorted in reverse):

```
sorted_dict={'A': 4, 'W': 4, 'T': 2, 'S': 2, 'I': 2, 'R': 1}
```

As you can see there are 2 keys with the same values ie. A and W.

I have written the the follow logic to get the max count

```
max_count = list(sorted_dict.values())[0]
max_count_letter_list = []
```

After iterating through each key in the dictionary, I add the letters with max counts to the list.

```
for letter in sorted_dict:
    if sorted_dict[letter] == max_count:
        max_count_letter_list.append(letter)
```

When printing to the console, it is printed as a list which is what I expect

```
print("Most frequent letter \"{}\" appears {} times"
          .format(max_count_letter_list, max_count))

Output: Most frequent letter "['W', 'A']" appears 4 times
```

However, if I have a single element in the list, it prints out like this:

```
Most frequent letter "['A']" appears 4 times
```

My expectation is to print like this: `Most frequent letter "A" appears 4 times`

Question: In the one line print statement, how do I print just a single element from the list without the brackets and if it is a list, it should print the list of elements. Do I need to write a if statement or is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Using an `if` statement to implement conditional logic seems like a natural choice. Why do you hesitate? You could of course use a ternary `if` operator in the print statement itself, but then it is just a matter of taste which one you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that fits for all could be to join items with a comma

```
print("Most frequent letter \"{}\" appears {} times".format(",".join(max_count_letter_list), max_count))

# Giving
Most frequent letter "A,W" appears 4 times
Most frequent letter "A" appears 4 times
```

If you want to handle them differently you need a condition to separate the cases : an `if` , then just write it normally or use the inline mode

```
 # inline
print("Most frequent letter \"{}\" appears {} times".format(letter_list[0] if len(letter_list) == 1 else letter_list, max_count))

# multi-line
if len(letter_list) == 1:
    print("Most frequent letter \"{}\" appears {} times".format(letter_list[0], max_count))
else:
    print("Most frequent letter \"{}\" appears {} times".format(letter_list, max_count))
```

---

Solution to shorten the before code

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
g = groupby(sorted_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
max_count, letter_list = next((count, [x[0] for x in vals]) for count, vals in g)
```

Comment: That works adequately, but OP seems to *want* the brackets in the case of more than one item.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you were thinking about...a conditional that prints differently based on how many items are in the list:

```
max_count_letter_list = ['A', 'W']
max_count = 4
print("Most frequent letter \"{}\" appears {} times".format(max_count_letter_list[0] if len(max_count_letter_list) == 1 else max_count_letter_list, max_count))
max_count_letter_list = ['A']
print("Most frequent letter \"{}\" appears {} times".format(max_count_letter_list[0] if len(max_count_letter_list) == 1 else max_count_letter_list, max_count))
```

Result:

```
Most frequent letter "['A', 'W']" appears 4 times
Most frequent letter "A" appears 4 times
```

Comment: The by the time I published my answer I got a notify that there was a new answer. And it was the same thing. lol

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Most frequent letter \"{}\" appears {} times"
.format((max_count_letter_list[0] if len(max_count_letter_list) ==1 else max_count_letter_list), 
max_count)
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This answer was already given.  You should not post the same answer that someone else has already given.  If you think a subtle change should be made to an answer, you should edit the existing answer.  That's why we have the ability to edit each others' answers.  Adding a second copy of what amounts to the same answer only confuses people and makes the question less valuable to people who come along later.  Please delete this answer to get your reputation points back.

Comment: OK, I saw your comment, so I understand why you posted this.  Still, the right thing to do is to realize that your answer is a duplicate and remove it.